# Is there any way to change Dialogflow Agent's default language?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to use text-based integrations, which works only on default language.I want to change the default language of agent from de to EN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved. For those who might face the same problem, Below are steps.

- Export the project as a Zip. (settings-> export/import )
- Create a new Agent with the required default language.
- Import the downloaded project from zip
  (settings-> export/import ).
  Note: there's another option of restore from zip, which will not change the default language, so don't do that.

Also, you have to change service account dependencies as we do for a new project. Thanks (solution got from try and fail, didn't have any documentation which tells the solution).